# Pinging webpage at specific times

Tags: heroku, cron

I am running a web application on heroku.

I have a couple cron jobs running on my server at 9am, 12pm, and 12am.

I need my web page to not have idled for me to run these cron jobs. As such I need some way to ping the web page just before these times to make sure it is running so that these cron jobs can be executed. I've seen uptime robot and new relic but they seem to only ping all the time for set intervals whereas I want to ping my webpage at specific times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

- Use the Heroku Scheduler addon to ping your dyno by making a request to it before the time you need your dyno to be awake, OR
- You can pay for a normal dyno. Heroku doesn't idle the normal dynos, only the free ones.

Comment: Ultimately Heroku Scheduler was too limited for my uses since it can only ping every 30 minutes. I took the plung and paid for hobby app account.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure a [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) to run and to wake up your web dyno by pinging it just before the time you need your web dyno to wake up.